# Create video from contents of webpage even if it's out of screen

Tags: macos, video, browser, screenshot, screen-recorder

I want to record the contents of a long webpage (even if it's out of my screen). Is there any tool to achieve that?

If video recording is not posible, take screenshot would be sufficient.

Any different approach is also welcome, i.e., if I just thought of a wrong solution and it's possible to enlarge windows without limits and then take a video or a screenshot of it, etc. then don't be afraid to tell.

For instance, if my display is 1280x800 for instance from superuser.com I would like to take a video that is 1280x4800 aprox. so that all the content is grabbed.

Any suggestion?

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion, but any solution to another system would also be upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) previously, and it has an option to grab a full page screenshot of a page larger than your screen. I do not know off hand whether the video capture would support it.

Do note, Snagit is paid software, but it has a very generous trial period (a month last I checked) with full functionality, so you can see if it suits your needs.